# UICollectionView Items not being reused properly (Swift 2.0+)

Tags: swift, image, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView inside of a TableView Cell. The CollectionView Cells themselves contain a UIImageView and a Label. The CollectionView Cells are supposed to display a users picture with their first name underneath. This data model is being structured within ViewDidLoad and has the correct data being output. However, my UICollectionViews are producing the user pictures and user names in erratic spots (i.e., user pictures and names are showing up on different TableView rows within the respective UICollectionViews of that different TableView row). I can try to elaborate on this more, if needed.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! wigoCollectionViewCell

    var sumSections = 0
    for  i in 0 ..< indexPath.section {

        let rowsInSection = eventFeed.numberOfRowsInSection(i)
        sumSections = sumSections + rowsInSection

    }
    let currentRow = sumSections + indexPath.row

    // Flip the collectionView
    var scalingTransform : CGAffineTransform!
    scalingTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
    cell.transform = scalingTransform

    // Make user profile picture circular and dispose of remaining image resources not visible
    cell.userPicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userPicture.frame.size.width/2
    cell.userPicture.clipsToBounds = true

    for (key, value) in (sortedArray[currentRow]["usersJoining"]!! as? NSDictionary)! {

        if key as? String != FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

            var name = String()
            var photoUrl = NSURL()

            name = value["userName"] as! String

            let nameSplit = name.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
            // Edit label
            cell.userNameLabel.text = nameSplit[0]

            // Make UIImage = user picture
            photoUrl = NSURL(string: value["userPhotoUrl"] as! String)!
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl)


            cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        }

    }

    return cell

}
```

On printing any particular variables, the output is exactly what I want. So this is entirely a matter of displaying the correct information in the cells.

I am using `prepareForReuse` correctly to the best of my knowledge.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    userPicture.image = nil
    userNameLabel.text = ""

    super.prepareForReuse()

}
```

The only solution I can think of revolves around using the `dispatch_async` methods to add the image in a background thread. However, I cannot seem to get that to solve my problem either.

I'm hoping someone here can help guide me with the correct method to solve my problem, as I haven't found any solutions through StackOverflow or the rest of the internet that solves my particular problem (or explains it very well for Swift 2.0+).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did, ultimately, discover the solution to my problem. So for anyone who is curious or has a similar problem:

The issue lied with iterating through an NSDictionary *within* the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. NSDictionaries are inherently unordered when created programmatically, and by iterating through the dictionary to get the data I needed resulted in it *appearing* as if there were load issues with the images in the cells within the `CollectionView`.

The solution was simply to mutate the `NSDictionary` into an `Array` and retrieve the values I needed from the array using `indexPath.item` as the index.

It's a *very* simple solution that simply didn't occur to me. So make sure your logic is solid if you're looking for a similar problem's solution as I was!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the following remarks will help you:

1. You initialize the `UIImage` with `NSData`, not with name, so you have to use the appropriate constructor for it:

   ```
    cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
   ```
2. A good practice is downloading the user's picture **asynchronously** (to prevent the UI freezes in case of poor internet connection):

   ```
   // Somewhere in your code
   func getImageFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) { 
       NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
           completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
       }.resume()
   }
   ```

   Inside your `tableView...cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

   ```
   // Make UIImage = user picture
   var photoUrl = value["userPhotoUrl"] as! String

   // Start working in background
   let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) { () -> Void in

   // Call the function with callback
       getImageFromUrl(NSURL(string: photoUrl)!) { (data, response, error) in
           guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }

           // Set the image in place in the main thread
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **If cells start displaying incorrect data while scrolling:** 
   I assume that there is a `UITableViewController` where you setup the inner `UICollectionView`. So, right after setting up each of the inner collection's data try calling `reloadData()` on it in the main queue like that:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       myCollectionView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

Comment: Interesting insight. I am assuming you are referring to where I have the delegate and dataSource set, for placing the reloadData()? If so, that still doesn't solve my problem unfortunately, it actually makes the output of the cells somewhat more erratic. 

I'll try to be more explicit of my problem and edit the above post.

Comment: @ColeRoe, so user picture doesn't match the user name next to it, am I right?

Comment: @ColeRoe also, do you cells have erratic locations initially, or after performing some actions (like scrolling)? Have you tried debugging the `collectionView...cellForItemAtIndexPath` func to ensure all the data take cells with the correct indexes?

Comment: Not quite. Say we have a TableView with two cells:  cell A has users 1, 2, and 3 added to the CollectionView that is within cell A. Cell B has users 1 and 4 added to its accompanying CollectionView. That's what the correct data model _should_ look like. However, my issue is that the CollectionView on Cell A is only showing users 1 and 3, and Cell B is showing user 2. The user CollectionView items on the TableView Cells seem to be getting displaced somehow.

Comment: The locations are erratic initially. Scrolling through the TableView or through the CollectionView does not produce different results. It's just upon initial load. And yes, I have gone over the data within `cellForItemAtIndexPath` multiple times with different variations of how the data is created and it is always being created and read correctly, just not displayed correctly.

Comment: not utilizing `NSData` is a typo in the copy-pasted code while I was making it more readable. Good catch, though! I have tried running the code asynchronously with little success, however I haven't used `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` so that may put me on the right track. I'll attempt this in a few hours and update you as to my findings.

Comment: Unfortunately, your updated answer still doesn't solve my issue. However, if I **DON'T** call `reloadData()` then the very first `TableView` cell displays the correct users within its `CollectionView`. Some `TableView` cell's `CollectionView`s are still incorrect after that. So for some reason that fixed only the very first cell within the table.

Comment: @ColeRoe Have you tried not to implement `prepareForReuse()` method at all? In general, you don't need this method if working with simple `CollectionView`. From the documentation: "You should not use this method to assign any new data to the view. That is the responsibility of your data source object"

Comment: I've noticed that there is a higher degree of irregularity with the images and labels displaying correctly _without_ `prepareForReuse()`. It's simply being used to reset the cells back to a defaulted state, which seems to be needed when there are multiple `CollectionViews` within a `TableView`. I'll have to play with it to see if there is a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer to this question but I noticed something I have seen in our mixed Swift/ObjC codebase that I want to comment.

One of the main differences between Swift and Objective-C is the type system and behaviour with `nil`. In Objective-C it is more or less safe to use nil (it may lead to unexpected behaviour but does not crash. Swift code will crash when `nil` is forced into a non-optional type. Crash happens also when a message is sent to a `nil` object.

In other words `nil` is very dangerous in Swift, therefore force unwrapping operator `!` and forced casts `as!` should be avoided.

In your code those dangerous operations can be seen in many places, hence the code can crash when the input is unexpected or e.g. the data for the image cannot be found for reason or another.

If your code was written e.g. along following lines it would be much safer and also clearer as it would include less forced casts and unwraps. The code is not tested though and I may have made some wrong assumptions on your datatypes.

```
guard let a = sortedArray as? [NSDictionary],
      let d = a[currentRow]["usersJoining"] as? NSDictionary,
      let currentUID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid 
    else { return nil }

for (key, value) in d {
    guard let k = key as? String where k != currentUID,
          let name = value["userName"] as? String
        else { continue }

    guard let urlString = value["userPhotoUrl"] as? String,
          let photoUrl = NSURL(string: urlString),
          let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl)
        else { continue }

    let nameSplit = name.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
    let firstName = nameSplit[0]

    cell.userNameLabel.text = firstName
    cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: data)
}
```

Ideally parsing data to type safe Swift datatypes should be done in some other place than `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! I'm surprised I hadn't thought of that by now as a solution to some scary issues that may crop up, I will be making some transitions away from the force casts and unwrappings. Thanks!